# Why does Apple not allow letters in Build Number in XCode?

Tags: xcode, build, build-numbers

Why does Apple not allow letters in Build Number in XCode? Especially considering their own build numbers always have a letter?

Just curious...

Comment: Apple doesn't want you to be like Apple.

Comment: Which apple build number has a letter in it?

Comment: This is a question only Apple can answer.

Comment: about a vendor policy rather than an actual programming question. Only apple knows why they do not allow this.

Comment: Sorry, I thought there might be a programming-related reason why.